# can we send mail without using the smpt port number host name

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am having username and password for a email account, but not smtp host name and port number,
I am using nodemailer.

Is it possible to send mail using only the username and password for the email account.

Edit: don't tell me to close, I have this doubt, If you know the answer tell me, this is not the silly thing, In my office they told me use only username and password. I searched online for it but did not got any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You would always need smtp server details all the time along with username and password. And completely depends on smtp server how it handles the smtp details.

Few examples of smtp servers -

```
smtp.gmail.com
smtp.sendgrid.com
smtp.zoho.com
smtp.dreamhost.com
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeMailer provides support for transports other than SMTP. You can check the link https://nodemailer.com/transports/. Looking in the documentation, it doesn't need SMTP server for these transports, you can give it a try.

In built support is there for below tansport.

- sendmail – for piping messages to the sendmail command
- SES – is a Nodemailer wrapper around aws-sdk to send mail using AWS SES
- stream – is just for returning messages, most probably for testing